# How to remove css with an jquery-animate or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I'm trying to use jQuery to remove the `css` element 'height'.  I don't want to make auto, or 0. Completely remove, but needs to do it with an animate like bellow example.  Maybe I could use an `addClass`, but not sure how I would animate.

Thanks!

Here is the code.  This works fine except there is on animate.

```
function ico_qa_sub_head(name,height) {

    var headName = name;

    if ($('#ico_qa_'+headName+'_id').css('height') < '1%') {
        $('#ico_qa_'+headName+'_id').css('height', '');

    }
}
```

This is what I would like to work.  Remove height all together but w/ an animate.

```
$('#ico_qa_'+headName+'_id').delay(0).animate({"height",""}, 100);
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

Answer (score 0):

The default value of `height` attribute is `auto`, not empty string. However, you can't animate to it from a set value using jQuery's `animate()` function. I hear you could use velocity.js which is smart enough to pre-calculate element's `auto` height value, considering content.

Here's the principle, if you want to do it yourself:

- create a clone of the element with `visibility:hidden;position:absolute;height:auto;`
- animate the original element's height from current value to clone's value
- when animation is done: delete clone and...
- set original element's height to `auto`.